# phone not charging but lightning bult is on

Tags: charging

my Android marshmellow phone isn't charging or connecting to pc, at first i thought it's the charger so i got a new one but the problem is still there, it shows that it's charging but the pourcentage doesn't increase or dicrease and if i connect it to my laptop it keeps connecting and disconnecting really fast.
also sometimes i can get it to charge by moving the charger around.
it became a frustrating game of luck so i'm wondering what may be wrong with it

Comment: it must be either that your PC doesn't supply enough current, or the phone USB port is broken

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like hardware issue. Moving charger around? Do you move end connected to phone or end in laptop? Depending on which end is one you moving it is probably charging connector broken or usb on your laptop. Try connecting other phone to that laptop, and connecting your phone to other PC so you will se where problem is. And maybe the battery is near dying.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the times, it's the phone's USB connector which gives bad contact("moving the charger around"). Buying a new USB connector and embed it yourself is not easy & another option is maybe to ask in your local repair store if they'll do it for you.